# Python module shared between docker services

Tags: python, docker, microservices

I have a project structure like this:

```
stack-example/service1
├── Dockerfile
└── main.py
stack-example/service2
├── Dockerfile
└── main.py
stack-example/shared_module
├── __init__.py
└── utils.py
stack-example/docker-compose.yml
```

Both *service1* and *service2* use *shared_module*.

```
#service1/main.py == service2/main.py
from shared_module import print_hello


def main():
    print_hello()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

So I have two *Dockerfile*s

```
#service1/Dockerfile (service2 has the same idea)
FROM python:3.11-slim

WORKDIR /service1

USER 1002

COPY . .
```

And *docker-compose.yml*

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  service1:
    build: service1/.
    command: python3 main.py
    ports:
      - 8012:8012

  service2:
    build: service2/.
    command: python3 main.py
    ports:
      - 8013:8013
```

Of course, if I try to run it, I will get Python import error, because he obviously  can't see *shared_module*.

What should I add to my source and docker files to achieve desired behaviour?

Comment: You don't appear to have any `links` assigned in your services, but this should help: https://medium.com/@sanjaypojo/docker-compose-sharing-code-between-services-9decd81654be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help of @ViaTech comment to my question, I found a solution:

*Dockerfile* should look like this:

```
FROM python:3.11-slim

WORKDIR /service1

USER 1002

COPY ./service1 /service1
COPY ./shared_module /service1/shared_module
```

docker-compose.yml should look like this:

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  service1:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./service1/Dockerfile
    command: python3 main.py

  service2:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./service2/Dockerfile
    command: python3 main.py
```

Comment: You can (and probably should) set the `CMD` in the Dockerfile, instead of providing an override `command:` in the Compose file.